# js can't match cookie name

Tags: javascript, cookies

```
function changesex(){
    var cookie=document.cookie;
    var sex;
    //alert(cookie);
    cooarr=cookie.split(";");
    for (var i=0;i<cooarr.length;i++){
        coo=cooarr[i].split("=");
        if (coo[0]=="sex"){
            sex=coo[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (sex=="male") sex="famale";
    else sex="male";
    var date=new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+3600*24*30);
    document.cookie="sex="+sex+";expires="+date.toGMTString();
    return sex;
}
```

this javascript function is used to change a cookie content,but I find a problem that this expression
    if (coo[0]=="sex"){ 
can be true only if i==0 and coo[0] equals the following string.
so the problem is the if expression can't be true even if coo[0] equals "xxx" string.
I spent a couple of hours on this and I was confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer when we got document.cookie and split by ";",their happen to be a space in front of the cookie name string,for example "sex" will become " sex",I don't know the exactly reason but I can't handle cookie now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a set of curly braces in the second half? After: if(sex=="male") ?